# It is to be selfish or pro-social

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> “We found that time pressure tends to magnify the predisposition that people already have, whether it is **to be** selfish or pro-social,” Krajbich said.

[Source](https://news.osu.edu/study-finds-you-act-most-like-you-in-a-time-crunch/)

---

What's the reason why "*being*" couldn't be substituted for "**to be**"?

Comment: *People already have a **predisposition to be selfish***. They can't have a *predisposition being selfish* - that requires an additional preposition: *time pressure tends to magnify the predisposition that people already have, whether it is **for being** selfish or pro-social,* But that's not so "elegant".

Comment: Why do you believe that "being" can't be substituted for "to be"?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Native English speakers said that it can't.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss Please include that information in your question. (By the way, native English speakers say incorrect things about their language very often.)